# iam getting Error while requiring or importing axios

Tags: javascript, axios, webapi, web-development-server, web-api-testing

I am trying to use axios in my js file but when i try to require it using

```
const axios = require('axios");
```

it shows error 'require is not defined'
if i try  importing axios using

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

it shows error 'cannot use import statement outside a module'
if i add type='module' in script tag
it shows error:
Access to script at 'file:///home/shubham-sharma/code/test.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.
test.html:7
GET file:///home/shubham-sharma/code/test.js net::ERR_FAILED

axios files have already set type to module in package.json

PS: i have installed axios globally but i also tried by installing it in the directory still got the error

the methods given in associated question i've tried all of them and my issue isn't resolved. this is a different question

Comment: do you see axios in your package.json file?

Comment: @RaviYadav — They are using a web browser, not Node.js. *package.json* is mostly irrelevant at that point.

Comment: @RaviYadav yes i see axios in .json file